# retornar array(matriz) de uma função em php

Tags: php, mysql, array

Estou armazenando os dados de um banco em uma array em um arquivo chamado *funcoes.php*:

```
    while($line = mysqli_fetch_array($execute)){
        $tabela[$a][$b] = $line['Activit'];
        $tabela[$a][$b+1] = $line['Usuario'];
        $tabela[$a][$b+2] = $line['Data_monit'];
        $a++;
    }
    return array($tabela);
```

e insiro a array retornada dentro de outra array em outro arquivo *filter.php:*

```
 $tabela = corrige_filter($data, $modulo, $usuario, $conexao);
 while($a < 10){
 echo '<tr>';
 echo '<td>'.$tabela[$a][$b].'</td>';
 echo '<td>'.$tabela[$a][$b+1].'</td>';
 echo '<td>'.$tabela[$a][$b+2].'</td>';
 echo '</tr>';
 $a++;
 }
```

Como esperado quando vou imprimir a tabela, o mesmo não retorna nada, então minha pergunta é, como passar a array da primeira função para outra array com o mesmo formato de matriz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simplesmente:

```
return $tabela;
```

Ao fazer `return array($tabela)` você está embrulhando a tabela toda (que já era array) em uma nova array.

Comment: Ah sim, era isso msm, achei q smp era preciso usar o array novamente
Obrigado :D